# data lost when reading xls file

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am connecting xls file using

```
String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=no;IMEX=1;""", openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

I am reading file in text mode (IMEX=1)

here is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArpYU-n8THyLdG1CUktDRGtIdEE0N0tDTHp3akRXenc#gid=0

but as given in file "Final Bill Date" not read by code

Is there any spacial code.

and also if file is already open then this cell get read :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not correct answer, but I just want to share my way to read XLS file.
I think best solution to read office files is using [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/)

It's fast, stable and free.You don't need MS Office interop assemblies at all.